# Converting Python script to be able to run in Spark/Hadoop

Tags: python, apache-spark, hadoop, hive, pyspark

I have a python script that currently runs on my desktop. It takes a csv file with roughly 25 million lines (Maybe 15 or so columns) and performs line by line operations.

For each line of input, multiple output lines are produced. The results are then output line by line into a csv file, the output ends up at around 100 million lines.

Code looks something like this:

```
with open(outputfile,"a") as outputcsv:
    with open(inputfile,"r") as input csv:
        headerlist=next(csv.reader(csvfile)
        for row in csv.reader(csvfile):
            variable1 = row[headerlist.index("VAR1")]
            variableN = row[headerlist.index("VARN")]
            while calculations not complete:
                do stuff #Some complex calculations are done at this point
                outputcsv.write(stuff)
```

We're now trying to convert the script to run via Hadoop, using pyspark.
I have no idea how to even start. I'm trying to work out how to iterate through an RDD object but don't think it can be done.

Is a line by line calculation like this suitable for distributed processing?

Comment: There's a couple of things you can do here first. There's no reason to keep re-indexing the headers on every loop, do it before the loop. This will add up over millions of iterations. Also, if you can fit the whole thing in memory, then you could try using `pandas`, which I believe will also transfer over to pyspark easily enough.

Comment: Thanks. I do index the headers before the loop, then just point to row[VAR1location] for example. Just put them in the loop here to keep my post cleaner and show where those locations come from. I have issues reading the whole thing into memory on my desktop which is why we ended up just reading csv line by line. I assume spark/Hadoop wouldn't have that problem?

Comment: That depends on the size of the cluster and the resources allocated to it. Another option you have is to try `dask` which should scale beyond your system RAM (though I've not used it myself).

Answer (score -1):

If you directly want to run the script, you could do so via spark-submit:

```
spark-submit master local[*]/yarn other_parameters path_to_your_script.py
```

But I would suggest to go for spark API's as they are easy to use. It will lower the coding overhead.

First you have to create a spark session variable so that you could access all spark functions:

```
 spark = SparkSession
   .builder()
   .appName("SparkSessionZipsExample")
   .config("parameters", "value")
   .getOrCreate()
```

Next, if you want to load a csv file:

```
file = spark.read.csv("path to file")
```

You can specify optional parameters like headers, inferschema, etc:

```
file=spark.read.option("header","true").csv("path to your file")
```

'file' will now be a pyspark dataframe.

You can now write the end output like this:

```
file.write.csv("output_path")
```

Please refer to the documentation : [spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/)  for transformations and other information.